# Solving 2 equations with 3 unknowns

Tags: systems-of-equations, problem-solving

Can please someone help me solve this puzzle, I want to find the right : **x,y and z**

here's my equations:

- (1+x*0.005556)*y-1=0
- (1.023895)*z-y=0

with (x,y,z)>0

Comment: One solution could be found by plugging in $x=0$, $y=1$ and $z= $....

Comment: It looks like you could freely choose any nonzero value for $y$ and solve the resulting equations for $x$ and $z$.  It's not clear from your problem statement what is meant by the "right" solution.

Comment: what do you mean by nonzero value ? the problem is that all the unknowns are positive and superior to zero... @MattiP.

Comment: Okay, well then you could take $x=180$, $y=\frac{1}{2}$ etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}(1+0.005556x)y-1=0&\implies x = \frac{\frac1y - 1}{0.005556}\tag{1}\\1.023895z-y=0&\implies z = \frac{y}{1.023895}\tag{2}\end{align}$$

From $(1)$, we have that $x > 0 \forall y\in(0, 1)$. From $(2)$, we have that $z > 0\forall y > 0$. Therefore, $x, y, z> 0\forall y\in(0, 1)$.

Comment: Thanks this helpful I wanted to be sure of myself.

Comment: I’ve the correct solution using Brent method, but don’t know how to get to the same values as the solution do you have any idea how this can be done ?